# Почему запрос sql ничего не возвращает?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, запрос

В бд есть таблица `opis` структура:

```
CREATE TABLE "opis" ( `discr` TEXT, `recept` TEXT )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему запрос

`select discr from opis
where recept = "Морс Черничный";`

Ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Значит в таблице он называется как то иначе. какая нибудь одна буква другая (может латинская) или пробел (или другой не видимый символ) где нибудь в конце затесался

Comment: Странно. Попробывал ввести вместо "Морс Черничный" "Салат Польза" все заработало.(Кавычки в наименовании, в столбце убрал)

Comment: Возможно, просто лишний пробел в конце или что-то подобное.